# replace $.off() removeEventListener of a element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to remove all event listeners on a element, it's simply by jquery:

```
$("#myEl").off()
```

now for some reason i must disable the jQuery lib and use vanilla js.

just for replacing, i use

```
el = document.getElementById("myEl")
el.removeEventListener(eventType) //for all listeners
of the type
el.removeEventListener() //for all listeners
```

it seems not work, if there is a simple way to do this?

Comment: You cannot simply pass in the eventType you have to also pass in the original function reference used in addEventListener [removeEventListener reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all `eventListeners` on an element, the best way is to clone the element.  If you want to use `removeEventListener()` you have to provide the event type and function to remove.

Here's an example of how to clone an element to remove all of the event listeners:

```
var oldElement = document.getElementById("myEl");
var newElement = oldElement.cloneNode(true);
oldElement.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, oldElement);
```